# Using CQRS to Improve a Legacy Monolithic System

Tags: architecture, data-modeling, cqrs, software-design

I'm working on a critical legacy system, which its data model is risky to change. The workload of this system is consist of fairly few writes, and lots of reads.

Now, I need to expose some new APIs to a few clients. To implement these APIs, I need to create new records or combine multiple records from the legacy system.

Considering the risks associated with changing the legacy system, and complexity of the data needed in new APIs, one solution for me is to use a [Reporting Database](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/ReportingDatabase.html).

Another possible solution could be using a CQRS-like architecture, so that the old system continues to store the data with its own data model (the Command part), and communicates any changes (events) using a message broker to another system, which stores the data in a way that is suitable for the clients to query (the Query part). Because this system is monolithic in overall, my events could only contain the identifiers of the changed entities, and the Query part can retrieve the full records by directly querying the shared database of the legacy system.

I know the complexities associated with a CQRS architecture, specially in distributed systems. On paper, it seems to solve lots of the difficulties, including modifying the legacy system. But still I'm not sure whether using the CQRS for solving the problem I described is a good idea or not, considering that some people believe CQRS should only be used in Greenfield projects.

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

CQRS is definitely not just for greenfield.  Converting large legacy systems to CQRS can be done successfully, it just takes a bit of finesse and time.

The key is to inject the event management into the legacy system before trying to build the reporting side.  Ideally you have a Repository approach in the legacy system where you can add writes to an event hub.  These event writes would be fire-and-forget async so they will add a little load to the server the legacy system lives on, but shouldn’t affect the response rate of individual writes.  If you don’t have a repository pattern in place, now may be the time to refactor.  If you don’t have a repository and don’t want to refactor one in, an unpleasant possibility is adding triggers to the DB to write out the events.

While injecting the event creation logic, you can also be designing the reporting side.  I wouldn’t start building the reporting side until most of the eventing logic is in because you will repeatedly discover new events you need from the legacy system that you didn’t plan on.  As you realize you need these new events, your plan for the reporting side will change and if you’ve already got it partially built, you can end up throwing away code you just wrote.

Once the events are in place, it’s just a matter of banging out the code to support the read side, which is laborious but trivial.

Be sure to give yourself enough time to do this.  Regardless of how much you plan, there’s a lot of trial and error in the process so it will definitely take you longer than you think.  If the deadlines are tight, replicating to a reporting DB would get the job done faster and cheaper, but it would be less flexible and require more maintenance going forward.

It's surprising how useful events are once they are in place.  Event listeners start popping up in all sorts of disparate systems you wouldn't have thought of, so if you can get management to buy off on the higher cost and longer timeline of the Eventing approach, it will pay off.